# django : which files are modified by migrate and makemigration?

Tags: django

I am having this issue of "django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: auth_user.username" on a brand new deployed django app.

I have no prreviously existant database, i have no files in my "migrations" folder. But I had done previous migrate and makemigrations on the source files for the deployment. So i'm wondering which files are affected by migrate and makemigrations commands?

I have deleted all the files in the migrations folder, but it seems some traces of a preceding user remain...

If you could provide me with some hints on the files where a trace of a preceding user exist, it would help me a lot.

Comment: Deleting migration files does not change your database, and that error stems from there being a duplicate user in your database. What do you mean with "no prreviously existant database" in practice?

Comment: But to answer your question: migrate doesn't change files, it changes the database based on migration files. Makemigrations creates migration files in your apps' migrations folders.

Comment: Thanks that answers my question. apparently the problem is with django 4. my createsuperuser is launched each time the container starts and apparently it creates duplicate superuser when in previous versions i got error when createsuperuser was launched when a superuser already existed

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dockerized django build : how to run only once createsuperuser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72888890/dockerized-django-build-how-to-run-only-once-createsuperuser)